# Disable submit button with jQuery until field and at least one chceckbox have values

Tags: html, jquery, forms, validation, contact-form-7

Imagine a newsletter subscription form. I have the form with just two different field types (`text`, `checkbox`), some of them need to be complete before submission. For sure, the required email field and at least one from the checkboxes. The submit/subscribe button should stay disabled until the condition from above is fulfilled. It also should revert from enabled to disabled state when the fields with values get empty.
I know this kind of question has been answered here a few times already.  I went through some examples from previous questions of this functionality working with [radios](https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/vdoMGX) and [checkboxes](https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/jZgQOV) or `<input>` fields only:

- [Disabling submit button until all fields have values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values)
- [Disable submit button until all form inputs have data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590673/disable-submit-button-until-all-form-inputs-have-data)

Some of them are answered but used code is outdated. Moreover, I'm not able to make a working code for my specific case. Quite close was [Disable submit button with jQuery until all fields have values (input, radio, select, checkbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405641/disable-submit-button-with-jquery-until-all-fields-have-values-input-radio-se?rq=1).
I used them all to make it to as far as here:
I can count a number of filled fields and enable the button when at least two of them are completed. However, two checkboxes (without the email) are enough - which is wrong. Can you please help me?

```js
$(function() {
    $('.subscribe-form').on('input',':input',function() {
        var inputs = $('.subscribe-form :input');
        var num_inputs = inputs.length;
        var num_filled = inputs.filter(function() { return $(this).is(':checkbox')?$(this).is(':checked'):!!this.value }).length;
        $('.subscribe-form :submit').prop('disabled',(num_filled+1<num_inputs));
    });
});
```

```css
.subscribe-form {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.subscribe-form__row {
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="subscribe-form">
  <div class="subscribe-form__row">
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your e-mail" />
  </div>
  <div class="subscribe-form__row">
    <p>Interests</p>
    <label for="checkbox-1">Nature</label>
    <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox-2">Travel</label>
    <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" />
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" disabled />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would count the email field and checkboxes separately.

Below, I added the `required` class to ease the selection of the required elements. Maybe you will need some not requiered fields someday.

Then, for the email field, I added an `email` class, because maybe you will want to add some first and last name fields in the future. I would suggest you to test it againt a regular expression instead of just empty... See this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) to start on that.

Then having `my_condition` in a variable makes the code easier to read and maintain **AND** to debug... ;)

```js
$(function() {
    $('.subscribe-form').on('input',':input',function() {
        console.clear() // Just for this demo...
    
        var email = $('.subscribe-form .required.email').filter((i,el)=>el.value!=="");
        var checkboxes = $('.subscribe-form .required:checkbox:checked');
        console.log("email",email.length,"checkbox",checkboxes.length)
        
        var my_condition = email.length>0 && checkboxes.length>0
        console.log(my_condition)
        $('.subscribe-form :submit').prop('disabled',!my_condition);
    });
});
```

```css
.subscribe-form {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.subscribe-form__row {
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="subscribe-form">
  <div class="subscribe-form__row">
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your e-mail" class="required email"/>
  </div>
  <div class="subscribe-form__row">
    <p>Interests</p>
    <label for="checkbox-1">Nature</label>
    <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" class="required" />
    <label for="checkbox-2">Travel</label>
    <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" class="required" />
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" disabled />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the super quick answer! Seems to work for me.
Could you please explain to me the `filter((i,el)=>el.value!=="")` syntax?
I can read the `value!=="` part but not the rest.

Comment: That is just an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and is equivalent to `function(i,el){return el.value!==""})` and `function(){ return this.value!==""}`. I named the arguments `i` and `el` for index and element... I did not use `i` because iI needed only the second argument here.